# How can I divide interface from the code?

Tags: c#, xaml, interface, code-behind

I know that I will be downvoted for this is kind of abstract question. I am aware that I'm missing the necessary specificity but this is a very important question to me.

I've been a WinForms C# user for ages. Now for work necessity I've been required to migrate to WPF. But what is puzzling me now is: am I using it properly? And specifically am I dividing xaml interface and code properly?

As a rule of thumb I put in the xaml interface all what I can and particularly all what's defined before hand. On the other hand I'm letting in code behind all what's programmatically defined. Is that correct?

And then what are the advantages of putting all what I can in the xaml interface?

Comment: MVVM, look at Microsoft Practices Prism. It's an awesome set of libraries aimed to help create the MVVM architecture in a WPF application, i.e. no more code behinds.

Comment: "what I can" - this is really abstract term. Can You explain it in more detailed way ?

Comment: As a guideline, if you can have zero lines of code-behind : do it :) Code-behind should be just UI-related (perhaps code is needed for some complex animations, or to inject your view models if you don't use something like Caliburn.Micro, but that's it.)

Comment: @Fabio and thanx for confirming what I said but why?!?! What's wrong with code behind? As a WF user I'm code-behind bount so I find it very difficult to understand why to avoid it?

Comment: well, to be perfectly honest, it would also be good to have SOLID principles in WinForms! react to events only to call a service that is supposed to get the job done and have nothing else in the handler. It's just that interactions between controls are not possible in WinForms without writing some code in the code-behind, whereas it's made possible with MVVM and WPF's bindings concept. if there were proper bindings in WinForms, you would do it too. your code in WinForms is a necessary evil ;)

Comment: Now I've been developing a quite complex program (complex for me) to deal with curves. It has zoom, pan and shape treatment (kind of very poor photoshop dealing with raster curves). So all menus and canvas and everything else is defined in the interface. Shape add, pan, zoom, restore, delete, treat, change, modify s/r are defined in the code-behind.... is that correct? I'm afraid of the answer....

Comment: you mean: the code to handle those transformations are done in the code-behind ?

Comment: you should look into WPF's _Commanding_ mechanism. that would be the proper way to go, and then have single-responsibilities services with a clean separation of concerns.

Comment: What I find difficult is that I've found no book or tutorial that leading me to have concrete guidelines. All what I got is a feeling that IT'S BETTER to avoid code-behind. But why and how still remains a mystery. How can a newbie start over? I've googled WPF commanding mechanism but nothing basic appeared.  Comunque grazie per i consigli

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is nothing wrong with code-behind as long it doesn't contain program logic. UI events and UI related code (for example: closing window or opening a new one) works perfectly in code-behind, and should be used there.

The principle behind MVVM is to decouple UI specific routines from your business logic and functions.

Also a very important rule to keep in mind is that the viewmodels you create should be able to be reused in lets say asp.net site, windows mobile app or universal windows app. So there's also no need to be UI aware. A lot of times I see implementations where people glue the view (ui) and viewmodels together inside one project to overcome some limitations of viewmodels. This is however bad practice and defeats the main purpose to decouple your view from viewmodels and allow actually to reuse your viewmodel in other projects.

To my students I advice therefore to start your viewmodel as portable class (this enforces you not to use ui elements inside your viewmodel) and depending of your view to extend them with platform specific functionality.

Reusing your viewmodels is then a breeze.

As glue between Viewmodels and views I recommend to use Prism [Prism Project page](https://github.com/PrismLibrary/) and [Nuget package](https://www.nuget.org/packages/Prism.Core/)

Comment: I was skeptical at first with Caliburn.Micro and their convention-based association of Views and ViewModels , but I found it was really smooth to work with it, even on a large project.

Comment: I see that I have a lot of work to do. Thank you also for the link you provided.

Comment: ;)

If you get down to this road correctly, it becomes a second nature for each project you create. I wish you a lot of success with this. And of course if you need any help, just ask.

Answer (score 2):

Write just as little code in the code-behind files as you can. most of the time, you can get away with *zero lines*.

To react to UI-induced events, you should use [the *Commanding* mechanism](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/ms752308(v=vs.100).aspx). This will call a method, not in your Code-behind, but in a *View-Model*.

Then you should google a bit on the *MVVM* topic.

The reason why you want to separate your logic from your code-behind is so that code-behind is all about UI.

if you have calculations to perform, you should not mix those concerns with the presentation layer.

For instance, you could want to have all your calculation in a portable library in the future so you could have a Windows phone version of your app, or a web-based service, or replace some heavy computation by a web-service.

The yes philosophy here is to embrace [*SOLID*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SOLID_(object-oriented_design)) principles, and WPF just promotes its use and allows to make cleaner separation for a better re-use and maintainability.

Comment: OK now I've got links to work on thanx a lot! Ripeto grazie mille

Comment: Prego ;) and one last for the road : you might want to have a look at this 3rd party library to avoid having to write code for View Model injection in the view : http://caliburnmicro.com/documentation/naming-conventions